# How to return array with one field defined by a string argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have a function that returns an array, how do I define the name of one of the columns in the return array with an argument?

Let's say instead of field 'qty' I want to have field whose name is passed in `myFieldName` argument.

```
var results = _.map(
    _.where(data, {
        UNDERLYING: product
    }),
    function (r) {
        if (r["QUANTITY"] != 0 && !isInArray(Date.parse(r["REPORT_DATE"]), errorDates)) {
            return {
                dt: Date.parse(r["REPORT_DATE"]),
                qty: (r["QUANTITY"] * multiplier)
            };
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: just do `r[myFieldName]`?

Comment: Closely related: [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Most closely a duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: As you can see I am already using that notation, the issue is I can't refer to r, as the new array is not r, I can't write r["qty"] instead of qty:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign properties, new or existing, after creating an object like so:

```
let foo = {bar: 1};
foo.baz = 2;
```

To do that with a dynamic name, you need to use the brackets accessor, like:

```
function assign(obj, field, value) {
    obj[field] = value;
}
```

In your case, you would do something like:

```
function getQuantity(data, field) {
  var results = _.map(
    _.where(data, {
      UNDERLYING: product
    }),
    function(r) {
      if (r["QUANTITY"] != 0 && !isInArray(Date.parse(r["REPORT_DATE"]), errorDates)) {
        var returnValue = {
          dt: Date.parse(r["REPORT_DATE"])
        };
        returnValue[field] = r["QUANTITY"] * multiplier;
        return returnValue;
      }
    }
  );
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is missing one bit, after the `returnValue[Field]` we need to add `return returnValue;`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the variable name to define a property in an Object literal. So, you may have to create an object and add properties to it, like this

```
var obj = {};
obj["dt"] = Date.parse(r["REPORT_DATE"]);
obj[myFieldName] = r["QUANTITY"] * multiplier;
return obj;
```

If you know few of the properties which are going to be there already, then you can define them in the object literal itself, like this

```
var obj = {
    dt: Date.parse(r["REPORT_DATE"])
};
obj[myFieldName] = r["QUANTITY"] * multiplier;
return obj;
```

---

If you are in an environment which supports [ECMAScript-6's Computed Property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), then you can simply do

```
return {
    dt: Date.parse(r["REPORT_DATE"]),
    [myFieldName] : r["QUANTITY"] * multiplier
}
```